# Display Data by calling function to another php page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

im still new to wordpress and not that good in coding much in php but i do know the basics. I have here my main code file for my plugin called hello-world.php and another php file called display-data.php. i kinda confused on how you display data by using a function to call it on another page which in mine called display-data.php here is my code for hello-world.php

```
function wpdisplay(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $result;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = '262'
    ", ARRAY_A);
    print_r($result);
}
register_activation_hook('activate_hello-world/display-data.php' ,'wpdisplay');
```

i have a button form in my main file that directs to display-data.php where it should display the data. i tried calling it by wpdisplay();

however it gives me an error like this. 
**Call to undefined function wpdisplay() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/hello-world/display-data.php**

hope you could help me and explain if there is something that i am missing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like error message says, you are calling a function that is not defined. To use a function that you have defined on a different file, you have to include that file.

Comment: i included the file via include 'hello-world.php;' another eroor pops up. **Call to undefined function add_action() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/hello-world/hello-world.php** on line 15. the code for line 15 is only this. add_action ('admin_menu', 'hello_menu'); ugh! i dont know whats wrong. zzz

Comment: add_action is a wordpress function, if you get this error is because you are not including file well. See this thread http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7398/how-to-include-php-files-in-plugins-the-correct-way